# i have modal dialog in foreach and want to show div animation after submit button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-blade

I have this in a table cell and pass #key to modal dialog

```html
<td> 
  <a id="myButton" href="#!" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#restoreBackup_{{ $key }}" class="btn btn-warning">Restore Backups</a> 
</td>
```

when I click restore button, then modal dialog with a form opened in foreach

my modal:

```html
@foreach ($backups as $key => $backup) 
  {{-- //restore section--}}
<div class="modal fade" id="restoreBackup_{{ $key }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="restoreBackup_{{ $key }}" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{ translate('Confirm Restore') }}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <b>Do you really want to restore this backup? {{ $key }}</b>
      </div>
      <form id="frm_restore_{{ $key }}" action="{{ route('backups.restore') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ $key }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="backuptype" value="{{ $backup['type'] }}" />
        <div class="modal-body">
        @if ($backup['type'] == 0)
          <div class="form-group">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Choose Your Restore Type</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-button">
            <input type="radio" id="radio30" name="restoretype" value="0" checked>
            <label for="radio30">DataBase And Folder</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio31" name="restoretype" value="1">
            <label for="radio31">Only DataBase</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio32" name="restoretype" value="2">
            <label for="radio32">Only Folder</label>
          </div>
        @endif
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Restore</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div id="animationdiv_{{ $key }}"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

As you can see, I have a div like this:

```html
<div id="animationdiv_{{ $key }}"></div>
```

I have a css code where the animation is defined:

```css
    .currently-loading {
        opacity: 0.75;
        -moz-opacity: 0.75;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75);
        background-image: url({{ static_asset('backup_restore_loading.gif') }});
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

In the case that I open a dialog modal outside the foreach loop and for example its form name is frm_backup, then I can display the animation in the JavaScript section if I submit it with the following codes:

```js
var frm_backup = document.getElementById('frm_backup');
frm_backup.addEventListener('submit', bmdLoading1);

//display loading message
function bmdLoading1() {
    var divloading1 = '';
    divloading1 = '<div class="currently-loading"></div>'
    $("#animation").html(divloading1);
}
```

but In the case that I open a dialog modal inside the foreach loop, i don't know how to pass $key and show div animation with $key
in this case each modal has a name like id="frm_restore_{{ $key }}" and each div has a name like id="animationdiv_{{ $key }}"

Comment: Please do not use the snippets to post non-runnable code. You can remove the first line of the snippet if you just used the editor for formatting reasons. Otherwise wrap in sets of three backticks

Comment: Alternatively and better: Post a [mcve] and paste RENDERED HTML instead of template

Comment: ok, thanks.I will comply

Answer (score 0):

It depends which element you're looking to add the animation "div" to. But you have to edit he html. You are creating a variable with the div you want to show but you're not assigning it to any location in your code. Something like

```
$('#modal-body').html(divloading1);
```

Comment: thanks Chris.i solved problem.thanks for your help